# Select subtitle track that embedded on MKV using gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I'm a newbie of GStreamer. Currently, I want to using pipeline to show subtitle.
This is my pipeline:

> gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=/home/root/video/F01_8subs_eur.mkv ! matroskademux name=d d. ! queue ! h264parse ! omxh264dec ! subtitleoverlay name=a ! waylandsink d. ! queue ! a. d. ! queue ! aacparse ! omxaacdec ! alsasink

The pipeline will show default English subtitle. However, in MKV clip has 8 embedded subtitles. I want to ask how way to select subtitles that I want to show ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only option to select subtitles in a pipeline is adding the correct caps in the demux before to the *subtitleoverlay* plugin.

The attempt here works fine (note that I have changed some plugins to the default standard ones but it it the same):

> gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=/home/test5.mkv ! matroskademux
>   name=demux demux. ! queue ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! subtitleoverlay
>   name=subs ! autovideosink demux.**subtitle_1** ! queue ! subs. demux. !
>   queue ! aacparse ! avdec_aac_fixed ! autoaudiosink

Changing **subtitle_1** to the other ones (from 0 to 7 in your case) you'll change the displayed subtitle.

Comment: Thank @jgorosdev. It works. But I want to ask new question that How can I use source C to select subtitle ? For my understanding, If use Playbin, we can do that but using the GstElement, it don't have properties that support select subtitle. Is that correct ?